# Python requests.get()

Tags: python, web, python-requests

```
response=requests.get(posturl,postData,headers)
print response.read()
```

I build the code,and debugger reports that

```
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try - `response = requests.post(posturl,data=postData,headers=headers)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `requests.post` to do POST request:

```
response=requests.get(posturl, postData, headers)
```

and to get content, use `response.content` (if you want byte string) or `response.text` (if you want unicode string):

```
print response.content
```